# Running SQLCmd with multiple scripting variables using Python subprocess.call

Tags: python, sqlcmd

This runs fine.

```
C:\> SQLCmd.exe -i "myQry.sql" -v Year=2018 Month=2
```

But these error out.

```
exitcode = subprocess.call(["SQLCmd.exe", "-i", "myQry.sql", "-v", "Year=2018 Month=2"])
 Or 
exitcode = subprocess.call(["SQLCmd.exe", "-i", "myQry.sql", "-v", ['Year=2018', 'Month=2']])
ValueError: SQLCmd failed in ['-v','Year=2018 Month=2']
```

Looks like 'Year=2018 Month=2' is not the right way to specify multiple scripting variables in a subprocess call.

I couldn't find the answer from the documentation. Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

`exitcode = subprocess.call(["SQLCmd.exe", "-i", "myQry.sql", "-v", "Year=2018", "Month=2"])`

If you combine `Year=2018` and `Month=2` into one string, python will treat it as a single argument, which cannot be recognized by `SQLCmd.exe`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!!